# Find and replace with regular expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

At the moment, I have a PHP function that gets the contents of a CSV file and puts it into a multi-dimensional array, which contains text that I print out in various places, using the indexes.

an example of use would be:

`$localText[index][pageText][conceptQualityText][$lang];`

The first index, `[index]`, would be the name of the page. The second index `[pageText]` would indicate what it is (text for the page). The third index, `[conceptQualityText]` indicates what the actual text is. The last index, `[$lang]` gets the text in the desired language.

so:

->page location

->what is it

->the content

->what language it should be displayed in.

This all worked fine in the previous PHP versions. However, upgrading to 7.2, PHP seems to be a bit more strict. I was a bit more green ~2 years ago when I first made this solution, and now know that since these indexes aren't defined as strings e.g. encapsulated in single quotes like so: `['index']`, they fit the notation of a superglobal (DEFINE). I didn't give it much thought back then, but now PHP seems to interpret them as so (superglobals), and so I get thrown the error that *x word* is an undefined superglobal.

My initial thought is to make a search and replace on my example string:

`$localText[index][pageText][conceptQualityText][$lang];`

using the regular expression functionality in Notepad++.

However, the example is just one of many, the notation of the array indexing is basically:

`$localText[index][index2][index3][$lang];`

**So my question is:**

How can I make use of the Notepad++ search and replace, using a regular expression, so that my index pointers become strings, instead of acting as superglobal variables?

e.g. make:

`$localText[index][index2][index3][$lang];`

into:

`$localText['index']['index2']['index3'][$lang];`

I will need some sort of logic that checks for whatever is inside the brackets and encapsulates them with single quotes, except for the last index, `[$lang]`.

I tried to give as much information as possible, let me know if anything needs to be elaborated.

I tried to refer to [these docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) without much luck.

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)|\B\$\w+)\K\[(?!\$\w+])([^][]+)]` and replace with `['$1']`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew your solution actually works (in theory). However, I have some concerns. I need to perform this in A LOT of files. This will affect every instance where the brackets `[ ]` occure, correct? So there will be "collateral" damage using this I believe. One way would be to check if it starts with `$localText`. Another concern is that I have already made some changes manually, where this will now be double quoting it, e.g. `$localText['index'][''index2''][''index3''][$lang];`.

Comment: Then use `(?:\G(?!^)|\B\$\w+)\K\[(\w+)]`. See https://regex101.com/r/E2O02P/1

Comment: What do you mean by "collateral damage"? The regex above only matches a `$` that is not preceded with any word char (it won't match in `oh$var`) and then will match any `[<1+word_chars>]` like substrings that follow one another. Please try your data at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2O02P/1) and let know if this is what you need. Else, see the other solutions below, although I see more potential "collateral damage" from Poul's solution and Martin's solution might really match any kind of triple brackets (at any location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using

this:

find: `\b(localText\[)([a-zA-z0-9_\-]+)(\]\[)([a-zA-z0-9_\-]+)(\]\[)([a-zA-z0-9_\-]+)`

replace: `$1'$2'$3'$4'$5'$6'`

and it works like a charm. Thanks for everyone who took their time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match:

```
\[[^'](\w+)[^']\]
```

The regex matches a Word between Square brackets unless it quoted.

Replace with:

```
['$1']
```

The regex will not match the last brackets because it contains a '`$`' sign.